# If an object contains a ManualResetEvent or AutoResetEvent does not get closed or disposed, does the parent object still become eligible for GC?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I have a class `MyClass` containing an `AutoResetEvent` (or a `ManualResetEvent`).

```
public class MyClass
{
    private AutoResetEvent _myWaitHandle;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _myWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    }
}
```

In the course of normal events, the program creates a new `MyClass`, uses it, and then lets it fall out of scope, with no further uses for the life of the program.  However, it never calls the `Dispose()` or `Close()` method of the `AutoResetEvent`, either directly or from a `using` block.  Per Microsoft, ["you should dispose of it either directly or indirectly"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle?view=netframework-4.5.2#remarks).

My question is this: does the presence of the not-explicitly-disposed `AutoResetEvent` prevent the parent `MyClass` object from being marked as eligible for garbage collection?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to make `MyClass` an `IDisposable`?

Comment: @Charlieface I would love to, but that would require several teams to make significant changes in several hundred classes of mostly-legacy code, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No. The `AutoResetEvent` object does not prevent an instance of `MyClass` from being garbage collected.

Once the instance of `MyClass` is out of scope, no further references to the object remain. Therefore the object is eligible to garbage collection.

The same applies to the instance of `AutoResetEvent` stored in `_myWaitHandle` with the difference, that a reference to this object is put on the finalization queue of the GC, to call the objects Finalizer before being finally garbage collected.

Even if the `AutoResetEvent` would store a reference back to its `MyClass` parent object, both objects are eligible to garbage collection, as long as neither one is referenced elsewhere.

For details on the topic of garbage collection, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now.  I've read the docs on GC before, and I was misunderstanding how IDisposable interacted with it.  All those "you'd better call Dispose() or we'll hunt you down" warnings got the better of me....